# How to create a heatmap in R with data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, heatmap, matrix-multiplication

I would like to generate a heatmap of some data so that the density can be seen indirectly.
But the problem is that the data had to be parsed from an xml file and were saved in a data frame. I know that heatmap needs a matrix as source and I tried to transform my data frame into such a matrix. But the result of the heatmap is, well, let us say it does not look very well. Can you help me please?

```
pdf("edge_connectivity_pdftest3.pdf", width = 7, height = 7)


library(XML)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(plotrix)

twentyfive <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MappingTest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://sourceforge.net/projects/alevin/ ./Alevin.xsd" xmlns="http://sourceforge.net/projects/alevin/" name="AdvSubgraphTestGenerator2">
<TestGenerator className="tests.generatorTests.AdvSubgraphTestRunner"/>
<ScenarioResult>
<ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.5"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="6.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="25.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="276.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="1.6936353132256952"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.7100219009060647"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="1.1567175867487764"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="SolelyForwardingHops" result="0.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="0.7102866433077278"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="2.0307953380742054"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="0.8828275034293551"/>
</ScenarioResult>
<ScenarioResult>
<ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.5"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="11.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="25.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
<ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="20.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="24.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="1.7460253697709436"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="1.576112684769838"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="2.350669297391729"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="SolelyForwardingHops" result="0.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="2.0118905996166037"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="2.515476723671439"/>
<ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="2.0488743711637802"/>
</ScenarioResult>
</MappingTest>'


test_twentyfive <- xmlParse(twentyfive)
vc2 = as.numeric(test_twentyfive['//*[@name = "EdgeConnectivity2"]', fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "result")])
number = as.numeric(test_twentyfive['//*[@name = "NumVNodesPerNet"]', fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "value")])
vc0 = as.numeric(test_twentyfive['//*[@name = "EdgeConnectivity0"]', fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "result")])

df2 <- data.frame(number,vc2)
df0 <- data.frame(number,vc0)
qrange50 <- range(0,vc2,vc0)

matrix <- data.matrix(df2)
heatmap( matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = heat.colors(256),  margins=c(5,10))
```

Comment: Have you checked how to do a heatmap with ggplot2? This might help http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/.

Comment: What do you *expect* it to look like (saying that it doesn't look good is vague)? Your data.frame is only 2x2...

Comment: Also, did you look at any of [these posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=heatmap+%5Br%5D)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new package out called heatmap.plus that may help you. It allows for a wider set of input formats than the original heatmap package. Documentation is here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heatmap.plus/heatmap.plus.pdf

You can also do very nice heatmaps using ggplot2. The geom_tile expression is the one you want. Here is an example (with code) that probably looks pretty close to the output you are trying to achieve: http://rpubs.com/daattali/heatmapsGgplotVsLattice

Answer (score 0):

It's a question about aesthetics so it's totally up to you, but is this looking 'good'?

```
ggplot(df2,aes(number,vc0,fill=number))+
geom_tile()+
scale_fill_continuous(low="white",high="red")
```

[image]